# Why does helm-locate work relatively slow for a small number of candidates?

Tags: emacs, locate, emacs-helm

There are two different cases in `helm-locate` behavior:

1) for example, pattern: **package**

`helm-locate` begins to show candidates immediately. (Note: `locate -i -e package` gives thousands of candidates.)

2) pattern: **package.rcp**

`helm-locate` waits a few seconds and begins to show candidates. (`locate -i -e package.rcp` gives 20+ candidates.)

I tried different patterns: 2) proceeds to 1) at aproximately 300 candidates. But `anything-locate` works quickly in both cases. How to make `helm-locate` work quickly for a small number of candidates?

Upd. I added issue https://github.com/emacs-helm/helm/issues/840 and screencast http://youtu.be/xL9JggHZmfs (there is 3 seconds delay: 18, 19 and 20).

Answer (score 0):

See "Fix slow down on small set of candidates in locate (#840)."

- helm-locate.el (helm-locate-init): Don't bind process-connection-type. https://github.com/emacs-helm/helm/commit/09bf98764b6d363326861780eeaba4e0f7993646